# Presist user logged in with React JWT Redux Without LocalStorage after refresh

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, jwt, local-storage

I am setting up an auth system in my react node-express psql app. I read  a lot of content and blogs on the internet regarding storing jwt but still need some clarification.

i have seen many tutorials like storing jwt in localstorage and their private routes will look like this

```
const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'))

 <Route
                {...rest}
                render={(props) =>
                    token ? (
                        <div className="relative ml-28 mr-10">
                            <Component {...props} />
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <Redirect
                            to={{
                                pathname: '/',
                                state: { from: props.location.pathname },
                            }}
                        />
                    )
                }
            />
```

1. **is this safe? if someone adds a new value named 'token' in localstorage with some random value will be considered as logged in right?**
2. **if localstorage is not recomended whats is the solution?**
3. **is it ok to send HTTP requests with JWT on every route load to verify the user ? (on each page loads)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, storing the JWT Token in the local storage should be completely safe and, as far as I know, is a best practice.

In your API, you should have some protected routes (needing an authorized user) like `POST /user-data` or `GET user-messages` ... and on the other hand, you should have other unprotected routes like `/login` and `/user-profile`.

For those that need authorization, you need to create a middleware called `authorize` that should be called on the protected routes. That middlware should take the jwt token from the request like `req.authentication` and decode it. Let's assume the token was encoded with the user email. Decoding it will give you back that email. With the email in hand, you can see if the user exists and if his roles permits him to make the action on the route.

With this, I think I implecetely answered the first question, if someone changes the accessToken in the localstorage from the browser, it won't cause any harm since it won't allow him to do anything.